# Timeout when running iPython nbconvert from command line

Tags: windows, automation, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I'm trying to automate IPython scripts using batch files and the Windows Task Manager. After much digging I've found that you can use Task Manager to trigger a BAT and through that execute the `nbconvert` package in order to run the Jupyter Notebook without the interactive bits.

In the BAT my code first "*turns the Windows cmd into an Anaconda Prompt*" with the code: `<anaconda3 path>\Scripts\activate.bat <anaconda3 path>`

(No formal CS education, so bear with me on this.)

That line allows me to run `conda` and `jupyter` commands out of the Windows cmd. I then run

```
jupyter nbconvert --execute --ExecutePreprocessor.enabled=True --ExecutePreprocessor.timeout=60 <Notebook>
```

I keep receiving a timeout error when this occurs. Yes, I could adjust the timer, but before setting the timer to 10 hours and coming back in the morning I'm hoping for some understanding of what is going on behind the scenes in `nbconvert`, and maybe some insights into how to get this working. The .ipynb file works fine when run through Jupyter Notebook. There is however a point at which the script is attempting to load several gb of data, which has taken ~20 minutes each time I've run it.

To that end - when `nbconvert` engages the Pre-processors, are they running the entire script preemptively? I'm struggling to find a reason as to why **nothing** opens, pings, runs, updates, etc... when executing the `nbconvert` command. I would expect at least an uptick in RAM usage, but as far as I can tell that isn't happening either.

How can I work around this, and what is going on behind the scenes when `nbconvert` is executed?

Traceback:

> ```
> C:\Users\User>jupyter nbconvert --execute "C:\Users\User\Desktop\_for_Python\CBSA.ipynb"  
> [NbConvertApp] Converting notebook C:\Users\User\Desktop\_for_Python\CBSA.ipynb to html  
> [NbConvertApp] Executing notebook with kernel: python3  
> [NbConvertApp] ERROR | Timeout waiting for execute reply (30s).  
> Traceback (most recent call last):  
>   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\preprocessors\execute.py", line 423, in _wait_for_reply  
>     msg = self.kc.shell_channel.get_msg(timeout=timeout)  
>   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\blocking\channels.py", line 57, in get_msg  
>     raise Empty  
> _queue.Empty
> ```

Comment: worth mentioning that  `--ExecutePreprocessor.timeout=` applies to execution of SINGLE cell of notebook not the execution of whole notebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by adding the `Anaconda3/Library/Bin` path to `c/windows/system32` PATH. Timeout was occurring due to DLL error, being returned as Timeout in command line.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone else facing this error with a correct path, I was able to extend the timeout using the flag --ExecutePreprocessor.timeout=300

According to the documentation:

> The timeout traitlet defines the maximum time (in seconds) each
> notebook cell is allowed to run, if the execution takes longer an
> exception will be raised. The default is 30 s, so in cases of
> long-running cells you may want to specify an higher value.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute_api.html?highlight=timeout#execution-arguments-traitlets): "The `timeout` option can also be set to `None` or `-1` to remove any restriction on execution time.". So that would be: `--ExecutePreprocessor.timeout=-1`